# Consumir HTTP. Dentro del IDE OK, fuera FAIL

Tags: netbeans, webservice, http, jar, ide

tengo un dilema que ya me está comiendo mucho la cabeza por que no consigo comprenderlo.

Mi caso es que estoy haciendo peticiones HTTP Post a una URL en la que tengo que enviar un JSON y me devuelve un JSON con la respuesta, en mi caso a Correos Express.

Todo funciona perfectamente cuando hago mis pruebas dentro del IDE de Netbeans, ejecuto mi programa, le doy a mi botón para que ejecute el siguiente código y me devuelva el número de seguimiento y la etiqueta a imprimir.

El problema está en que cuando hago el "Clean and Build" para dejar preparado mi .jar para ejecutar desde cualquier ordenador, en vez de recibir un responseCode = 200 como que todo es OK cuando lo hacia desde el IDE, ahora desde fuera recibo el 400.

No entiendo como sin alteración, las peticiones hechas desde el .jar fuera del IDE no se realizan correctamente.

Aquí dejo el método que utilizo, donde Envio y Recepción son clases creadas a medida de los JSON para poder manejarlos de manera mas sencilla, ya que siempre se envia y recibe los mismos parámetros.

```
public Recepcion enviarRecibirEtiqueta(Envio env) {

        Recepcion recep = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www......./json/grabacionEnvio"); //PRUEBAS

            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
             
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            String auth = "**:**";
            byte[] authutf = auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(authutf);

            String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            

            Gson jeison = new Gson();

            String input = jeison.toJson(env); //Transformo los datos del json a string para enviarlo en el cuerpo de la peticion
            System.out.println("lo que envio: " + input); //visualizar yo el contenido
            byte[] inputdata = input.getBytes();

            try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.write(inputdata);
            }

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String jsonReply;
            if (responseCode == 400){
                System.out.println("Conexión Fail");
                InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
                System.out.println(convertStreamToString(response));
            }
            if (responseCode == 201 || responseCode == 200) {
                System.out.println("Conexión OK");
                InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
                jsonReply = convertStreamToString(response);
                recep = jeison.fromJson(jsonReply, Recepcion.class);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("URL mal formada");
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getCause());
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }
        return recep;
    }
```

Comment: solo veo que controlas los codigos 400, 201 y 200 que pasa si el servidor te da un error 404 o 500??

Comment: No lo había tenido en cuenta, añadiré codigo para interceptar esos errores, pero aun así el que siempre recibo es el 400 cuando lo ejecuto desde el .jar

Comment: ese error quiere decir que la petición esta mal formada: cuando eso ocurre muestra en un alert/consola los datos que armaste en la petición y valídalos...

Comment: una vez que hayas validado lleva los datos a una aplicación de prueba que pueda validar el error de tu malformada petición ... yo uso POSTMAN

Comment: Si, utilizo SoapUI para comprobar que los datos están bien formados, además de que con este código, cuando lo ejecuto desde Netbeans se hace correctamente, osea que los datos están bien, pero cuando ejecuto este mismo programa despues de Limpiar y Construir, es cuando viene el error 400 en la misma función

Comment: esta bien raro .... puede ser hasta problema de firewall...

Comment: Revisa que no sea un problema de antivirus bloqueando la petición del JAR o cosas externas :/

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez perdona por no anotar antes, soy nuevo por aquí, pues alomejor va a ser eso ahora que lo pienso, porque el IDE la primera vez que lo usas te pide que le permitas en el firewall, en caso de un jar, no, mañana cuando pueda acceder al código lo probaré, gracias.

Comment: @Alfabravo también puede ser, uso Norton, quizás aparte del firewall, puede ser que también me esté dando problemas, gracias, lo probaré mañana.